# Blazor Server side, set parent class name based on child class name

Tags: css, conditional-statements, blazor

I have a EditForm with MatBlazor Expansion panels. I am trying to set the individual panels border color if any of the form fields are invalid inside it. I am trying to achieve following..

```
<MatExpansionPanel Class="@(<bool>ChildElementHasValidationMessage() ? "invalid-red-border": "")">.....</MatExpansionPanel>
```

I am OK with simple equivalent css solution to find a parent element. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Style` instead `Class` to override css:

```
<MatExpansionPanel Style="@(your expression);"
```

I answered a related question about MatExpansionPanel: [Mat Blazor mat-expansion-panel remove elevation/border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295435/mat-blazor-mat-expansion-panel-remove-elevation-border)

**Edited**

I wrote my own component to send `EditContext` on changes. I pasted it below. This is how it works:

```
<h1>@ShowDemo</h1>

<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="@SaveItem">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <MyValidationSneak UpdateDelegate="@( (ctx)=>UpdateUI(ctx) )" /> 
    <InputText id="ItemName" @bind-Value="@model.ItemName" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.ItemName)" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {

    string ShowDemo = "res de res";

    protected void UpdateUI(EditContext ctx)
    {
        var _fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create( () => model.ItemName );
        ShowDemo = string.Join(", ", ctx.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier) );
    }

    ItemModel model = new ItemModel();

    private void SaveItem() { }

    public class ItemModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string ItemName{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

See it in action at [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/488ave6q):

[image: Demo]

The `MyValidationSneak`:

```
public class MyValidationSneak: ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    [CascadingParameter] EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Action<EditContext> UpdateDelegate { get; set; }

    private readonly EventHandler<ValidationStateChangedEventArgs> _validationStateChangedHandler;
    public MyValidationSneak()
    {
        _validationStateChangedHandler = (sender, eventArgs) => GoUpdate();
    }

    private void GoUpdate() => UpdateDelegate(CurrentEditContext);

    private EditContext _previousEditContext;
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (CurrentEditContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(ValidationSummary)} requires a cascading parameter " +
                $"of type {nameof(EditContext)}. For example, you can use {nameof(ValidationSummary)} inside " +
                $"an {nameof(EditForm)}.");
        }

        if (CurrentEditContext != _previousEditContext)
        {
            DetachValidationStateChangedListener();
            CurrentEditContext.OnValidationStateChanged += _validationStateChangedHandler;
            GoUpdate();
            _previousEditContext = CurrentEditContext;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {}

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        DetachValidationStateChangedListener();
        this.Dispose(disposing: true);
    }
    private void DetachValidationStateChangedListener()
    {
        if (_previousEditContext != null)
        {
            _previousEditContext.OnValidationStateChanged -= _validationStateChangedHandler;
            GoUpdate();
       }
    }                
}
```

[Get code at github](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/EditFormCaptureValidationChanges)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But what I am looking for is an expression that can check if the child element has invalid fields, only then apply the style.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I see it is not simple. But yes, this is what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: They are simpler ways, but this is one of the the more elegant solutions (for me). I shared code on github to make it easy for you.